# specifying simplepie cache location?

Tags: php, simplepie, document-root

Ehrm. I know this seems simple (as pie, har har),  but I keep getting a

```
Warning: /cache/ is not writeable. Make sure you've set the correct relative or absolute path, and that the location is server-writable.
```

Here is my situation.  I have simplepie pulling in feeds from various levels and folders on my domain. So if it works in one spot, then I get this warning in others.  (Such as it is in a subfolder.)

SO, I am trying to specify the actual full path location by editing line 501 on the simplepie.inc file to

```
var $cache_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/cache/";
```

BUT, this is a syntax error.....

so,  A) why? I know I am missing something stupid.

and B) is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 5):

What about http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/set_cache_location ?

Comment: Good call!  I did see that, however, I would like to set it ONCE instead of setting it every time I build the calls since it will always be in the same place.

Comment: There's currently no way to set a default cache location for all SimplePie objects, but you could symlink the cache directory if you don't want to write code.

Answer (score 2):

create one folder in your application 
let suppose folder name is cache
add this line to your php page.
$feed->set_cache_location($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your application name/cache');